# Random.Range is not working for some reason

Tags: unity-game-engine

So `Random.Range` isn't working for me for some reason and I don't know why my code is below

```cs
public class Random {
     int num = Random.Range(1, 9);
}
```

Note: I am using Unity for this and sorry if this explanation is bad im really new to coding.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 reasons:

- Your class name should not be `Random` itself.
- The Range command must be given inside the method. Because its value
  is dynamic.

```cs
public class ClassA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void Start()
    {
        var num = Random.Range(1, 9);
        
        Debug.Log(num);
    }
}
```